# Python code in a Google Cloud VM stops working after a while?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, discord

I have a discord bot running through my Python script. I have a Google Cloud VM where I run my Python code in Wing IDE. After a day or two the discord bot stops working and I have to rerun the Python code in the IDE. There are no error messages.

What could be causing the VM to stop my code?

Comment: Does the python process die or does it just stop doing new work?

Comment: It stops doing new work, when I open up the VM it shows my IDE open with no errors or messages in the dialog box. Im trying another ide/way to run to see if its that.